# Providing space between two buttons

Tags: html, css, margin, limesurvey

I have a situation where I cannot change the css files but not html/php. I have two buttons in the page with ID's "moveprevbtn" and "movenextbtn". They are at present closely located. Using Css or using any scripts I need to spread them away. I am not being able to do it.

With CSS I tried something like this,

```
  #moveprevbtn {
    position: relative;
    left: -30px;
}

#movenextbtn {
    position: relative;
    right: 30px;
}
```

But didnt help me much. Any suggestion.

I am talking in context of LimeSurvey. PHP/MySql

[image: Here the IDs Previous button and next button respectively]

Here the IDs Previous button and next button respectively. I can edit the CSS files. I have to move them to left and right by providing space between them.

Comment: Can you change your CSS, or not?  And how can we help you with your CSS without seeing your markup?

Comment: could you show a live demo of your code?

Comment: Do you want them on top/bottom OR side-by-side ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are looking to have the buttons side-by-side and just spaced further apart. If that is correct, this would work.

```
#moveprevbtn {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
}

#movenextbtn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
}
```

ALTERNATIVELY:

you could just add space between the two buttons like this:

```
  #moveprevbtn {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -30px;
  }

#movenextbtn {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: -30px;
}
```

The first option will put your buttons 30px from the right and 30px from the left side of your view port.

The second will should simply subtract space on the opposing sides of your buttons which adds space between the two.

Comment: A few reasons this would not change anything. Either because there are CSS rules further down your style sheet that are overriding these rules, you have a second style sheet that is loaded after this style sheet is loaded, the changes are being saved in the wrong place, or the styles for the buttons are inline styles. One other possibility is that it was changing the styles and the previous results were cached. This would cause an instance where it doesn't look like anything is changing.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right and you want your buttons side by side with space in middle:

Add `margin-left` to `#movenextbtn`

```
#movenextbtn {
    background: transparent url(myNextImage.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    margin-left:100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/F3Zjx/1)